# Can this be a good approach to making an OS more safe against malware?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, security, operating-systems

Every computer can have two hard disks, one which will store the OS and related files and will not be accessible to other code. The OS HDD will only be able to connect to a secure server for updates and nothing else. All the c@ap software will go on the other HDD.

Comment: And how do you intend to make files on disk 1  'not accessible to other code' ?

Comment: Yes it will make your computer safe from malware.  It will also make your programs 'safe' from usage.

Comment: @spuder Maybe by using something similar to SELinux. I don't know if there is a windows equivalent, though.

Comment: Questions in SU should be about practical, not theoretical, problems. This being said, It would depend entirely on how applications need to access the kernel and what permissions it allows to the processes. On how it is written, it is too broad of a question to be clearly answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the operating system and the current user(s) can access the drive, then the number of drives does not increase security.

Even with two drives, one for the operating system, and another for storage and applications, there is no increased security. There is increased uptime in the event of malware though. Only the core of the server would need to be rebuilt, thus making recovery time less.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple hard drives can increase security provided that you have only a single internal hard drive exclusively for the system and all others external removable drives.

1. Use the smallest possible SSD for the system (say 32G) and 1T USB3 drives for the others.
2. Clone the system drive so that you can quickly restore if you do catch something.
3. Keep one USB drive exclusively for connection to the internet.
4. Use all others only when off-line.
5. Virus check *all* software before installing.

I can't remember when I last had a virus, must be many years ago.

[see also](https://superuser.com/questions/633092/what-is-the-simplest-free-physical-solution-to-backing-up-files-from-multiple-co/637265#637265)